# Syntax to call generic C# method from NLua

Tags: c#, generics, lua, xna, nlua

I'm having some trouble figuring out the correct syntax for calling a generic C# function from Lua with NLua.

I'm trying to call the following C# XNA function from Lua

```
GameWorld.Instance.Content.Load<Texture2D>("player");
```

But I'm having some syntax trouble with the generic `<T>` part. My current lua call looks like this, which is clearly not correct, since I'm getting a LuaScriptException.

```
GameWorld.Instance.Content:Load<Texture2D>("player")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm create class AssetManager with pair of Load/Get methods for each asset type.

```
class AssetManager
{
    private ContentManager content;
    private Dictionary<string, Texture2D> textures; // fonts, sprites, models and so on

    AssetManager(ContentManager  pContent)
    {
        this.content = pContent;
        this.textures = new Dictionary<string, Texture2D>();
    }

    public void LoadTexture(string pName, string pAssetName)
    {
        this.textures.Add(pName, this.content.Load<Texture2D>(pAssetName);
    }
    public Texture2D GetTexture(stirng pName)
    {
        return this.Textures.ContainsKey(pName) ? this.Textures[pName] : null;
    }
}
```

Simple usage from both C# and Lua.